# How to use commit in MERGE statement in oracle 19c?

Tags: oracle, merge, insert, updates, commit

Is it possible to use a commit statement in MERGE syntax in oracle 19c? I want to perform a commit after every 1000 updates and after every 1000 inserts, how to achieve this?

```
MERGE INTO target_table 
USING source_table 
ON search_condition
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET col1 = value1, col2 = value2,...
        WHERE <update_condition>
        [DELETE WHERE <delete_condition>]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (col1,col2,...)
        values(value1,value2,...)
        WHERE <insert_condition>;
```

If the above is not possible, then how would you generally find if 1000 rows are inserted/updated and perform a commit accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, not within `MERGE` itself. Commit once, when everything is done.

Besides, why would you want to commit that frequently? What benefit do you expect?

If it MUST be as you described, use a loop and do it in *chunks* of 1000 rows, then commit. Beware of ORA-01555 which *might* (or might not) happen when you frequently commit within a loop.

Comment: So you mean to say, my approach has to be like insert statement followed by a loop to commit 1000 records. I was asked this question in a online quiz, I know these type of commits won't be applied in real time scenario in business.

Comment: Ah, quiz. Loop it is, but you might put that "1000 rows" condition into `source_table` clause so that every loop iteration manipulates 1000 rows.